How to import ETIM file into Pimcore classification store?
I want to import an ETIM XML/CSV/XLSX file(https://www.etim-international.com/downloads/?_sft_downloadcategory=model-releases&_sft_version=9-0) into the Pimcore and create a classification store.
I almost checked out the entire internet and tried ChatGPT as well but couldn't find any proper solution.
So far I have found:

Different ways to import ETIM into Pimcore:
i) Via PAID plugin:
https://digital-commerce.blackbit.com/en/data-director-new-command-for-importing-etim-categories-into-pimcore
https://pimcore.com/en/developers/marketplace/blackbit_digital_commerce/pimcore-data-director-bmecat_e139615
ii) Via free plugin: https://github.com/DivanteLtd/pimcore-classification-store-importer/tree/master
iii) Via custom code:
Via custom code, there are also 2 ways: By reading CSV, XML file or by calling ETIMAPI(https://etimapi.etim-international.com/) directly which requires client_id/client_secret
Ref links:
https://github.com/orgs/pimcore/discussions/12962#discussioncomment-4322879
https://github.com/orgs/pimcore/discussions/13708

Any help would be appriciated.
Thanks
